# Error while Messaging with Huawei E3531 using matlab

Tags: matlab, at-command

I am using Huawei E3531 model for sending message by interfacing it with matlab. But it always shows an error. Do I need to unlock my Huawei dongle?

If not, what is the actual problem? I am using the following code:

```
clc;
clear all;
global BytesAvail;
global A;
global B;
tx ='ATI';
tx1=char(13);
tx2=char(26);
tx3='AT+CMGS="+919526018418"'; 
tx4= ' This is a test msg ';     
tx5='AT+CMGF=1';

s = serial('COM5'); 

s.baudrate=9600;
fopen(s);
s.Terminator = 'CR';

fprintf(s,'%s', tx); 
fprintf(s,'%s', tx1); 

BytesAvail=s.BytesAvailable;
    if(BytesAvail > 0), A=fread(s,BytesAvail,'char'); end
A;
sprintf('%c', A)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Send SMS%%%%%%%%%%%%
fprintf(s,'%s', tx5);
fprintf(s,'%s', tx1); 
fprintf(s,'%s', tx3);
fprintf(s,'%s', tx1); 
fprintf(s,'%s', tx4);
fprintf(s,'%s', tx2);
BytesAvail=s.BytesAvailable;
    if(BytesAvail > 0), B=fread(s,BytesAvail,'char'); end
B;

fclose(s)
```

The error is this

```
??? Error using ==> serial.fprintf at 144
An error occurred during writing.

Error in ==> message at 20
    fprintf(s,'%s', tx);

>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is caused by some virtual serial port drivers not supporting functionality equivalent to a physical serial port, and the way Matlab handles communication with the virtual serial port.

A possible solution would be to upgrade to the latest drivers (provided by the vendor of the serial port adapter).

If the error persists even with the latest drivers for the virtual serial port adapter, there is the possibility to use an alternate means of communication with serial COM ports through the VISA interface available through the Instrument Control Toolbox.

The VISA software libraries provided by Agilent/Keysight (Agilent IO Libraries) handle serial COM port communication separately from the Matlab serial port interface.

The Agilent IO Libraries can be downloaded at [the following URL](http://www.home.agilent.com/en/pd-1985909-pn-E2094/io-libraries-suite-162?&cc=US&lc=eng).

To add the virtual serial port as a VISA resource name (also refer to screenshots):

1. Open Agilent Connection Expert
2. Right click on on the desired serial port item ('COMxx') located in the 'Instrument I/O on ths PC' column, and select "Add Instrument" from the pop-up context menu.
3. In the following dialog box, uncheck "Auto-identify this instrument" and click OK.
4. Verify that the virtual serial port has been assigned a VISA resource name (for example ASRL4::INSTR)
5. Open MATLAB and run the following commands in the command window to show the VISA object constructor name corresponding to the VISA resource name:

   visaInfo = instrhwinfo('visa', 'agilent');
   visaInfo.ObjectConstructorName;

An example code for virtual serial port communication with MATLAB Instrument Control Toolbox and the VISA interface:

```
% --- Open and write
v = visa('agilent', 'ASRL4::INSTR');
fopen(v);
fprintf(v, 'abc');
fwrite(v, [97 98 99]);
fclose(v);

% --- Clean up
delete(v);
clear v;
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: sometimes it shows like this ..    
Error using serial/fopen (line 72)

Open failed: Port: COM23 is not available.

 Available ports: COM13.
Use INSTRFIND to determine if other instrument objects are connected to the requested device.

Error in smsModule (line 19)

fopen(s);

but i am sure that no other applications are using this COM port.

Comment: Well you have to check first on which COM port your device is connected.

Comment: You hardware is very specific, so no one can try and reproduce your error to debug it. You have to be very précise in your problem. This is probably not a Matlab question by the way, so you're asking the wrong place. Try forums where users have already done connections with this type of hardware.

Comment: And have you tried what is decribed in the solution ?

Comment: I have downloaded Agilent IO libraries but i don't know how to open Agilent Connection Expert... Can you please contact me..?? +919526018418   
and I tried this method after watching this video link below.. there that guy simply done this using  huawei modem..https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2jzGmUDDqo

Comment: @ARUNBALANNV: OK, glad it helped ! Please flag the question as aswered such that the community knows that you no longer need help on this question.